I need division of two varchar2 defined columns in NUMBER(19,10) format in Oracle
I am executing below sql not getting expected result, I am converting the columns into NUMBER(19,10) before division but I need the result (after division) to be converted into NUMBER (19,10);
SELECT DISTINCT 
CAST(TO_NUMBER(BASE_AMT) AS NUMBER (19,10))/CAST(TO_NUMBER(ACT_AMT) AS NUMBER (19,10))
FROM CUSTOMER;

Note: BASE_AMT and ACT_AMT columns are varchar2 defined

What does the result end up as with your current expression?

I think that you are confusing data type with string format. If you divide 2 numbers of type NUMBER (19,10), the result will be of type NUMBER (19,10) as well. Oracle indeed maintains both precision and scale during arithmetic operations. The data type determines how a value is stored internally. The string format determines how a value is displayed after having been converted to a text type (VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR@, etc.). Don't store numbers as VARCHAR2 just because you want them displayed differently! Apply a format in the front end instead when displaying the value.

You should have probably applied cast function to final result, e.g.
SQL> create table customer (code varchar2(3), name varchar2(8), base_amt varchar2(5), act_amt varchar2(5));

Table created.

SQL> insert into customer (code, name, base_amt, act_amt) values ('100', 'Scott', '33', '4');

1 row created.

Like this:
SQL> select distinct
  2    cast(to_number(base_amt) / to_number(act_amt) as number (19,10)) result
  3  from customer;

    RESULT
----------
      8,25

SQL>

